# Modeling with variation: write an equation describing a direct relationship where $y$ varies directly as the cube of $x$ and when $x=36$, $y=24$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to write an equation describing a direct relationship where $y$ varies directly as the cube of $x$ and when $x=36$, $y=24$

The solution provided at the back of my book says $y=10x^3$, I am unable to arrive at this. My working...

General formula (find $k$):
$$y=kx^n$$
Plugging in:
$$y=kx^3$$
$$24=k36^3$$
$$24=46656K$$
$$k=\frac{24}{46656}$$

I arrive at a very different value of $k$. How can I arrive at $k=10$ per my textbooks solution?
$$$$

Comment: The textbook (or the question) is wrong. Obviously $24 \ne 10\times36^3$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Just in case I have missed anything, the textbook is online here. I'll link to two pages, first the page with the question and then the one with the solution: Scroll to exercises at the end. Chapter 5, module 8, section excercise 7: https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/5-8-modeling-using-variation. The solution is here under 5.8 section excercises https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/chapter-5

Comment: Judging by how $x$ and $y$ are the same for Q6 and Q7, I'll take a wild guess and say it's a typo in copying and pasting.

Comment: Aha! I never noticed that (I only do every other question since those have solutions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=kx^3$, then
$$
k=\frac{y}{x^3}=\frac{24}{36^3}=\frac{24}{46656}=\frac{1}{1944}.
$$
So definitely not $10x^3$.